# What is the technical term used to call what is Ant Design's skeleton?

Tags: css-frameworks

I see Google and YouTube using this method to gracefully indicate elements loading before they are fully available.

What I'm looking for is what Ant Design has called a ["skeleton" component](https://ant.design/components/skeleton/).

I want to be able to search for it when it comes to other frameworks, so I'm curious what name the industry gave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Loading Placeholder.